# Line gaps between HTML elements inside pre tag

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I tried to insert some html tags in [pre tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) but there was a big gap between lines

Here's my HTML code

```
<h5>Help Message</h5>
    <pre ng-show="panel.info_mode == 'markdown'" ng-bind-html="panel.help_message | markdown"> </pre>
    <pre ng-show="panel.info_mode == 'text'" ng-style='panel.style' ng-bind-html="panel.help_message | striphtml | newlines"></pre>
    <pre ng-show="panel.info_mode == 'html'" ng-bind-html="panel.help_message"></pre>
```

panel.help_message will have some html elements like

```
<h1>Dillinger</h1>
<p>Dillinger is a cloud-enabled HTML5 Markdown editor.</p>
<ul>
<li>Type some Markdown text in the left window</li>
<li>See the HTML in the right</li>
<li>Magic</li>
</ul>
```

and the result was like following photo

[image]

So what's the cause of this line gaping

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can just use a `<div>` instead of a `<pre>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because text in a < pre > element is displayed in a fixed-width font (usually Courier), and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.If you want to have you own design for displaying then try to wrap your text in div or some tag with your defined class and write you own css.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers render such invalid markup in various ways. It’s unspecified and undocumented, but basically they try to apply the default rendering of heading elements etc. *and* the special `pre` rendering. They don’t fit well; they weren’t designed to fit.

A [`pre` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-pre-element) can contain text and text-level markup that does not change font size. If you use other content, you can expect oddities. It is unclear what you want and how it is best achieved, but the markup should be re-designed.

Answer (score 1):

Because browsers have some default value like padding, margin, line-height, etc.

You can reset those values:

```
h1,p,ul{margin:0;padding:0;line-height:normal;}
```

Answer (score 1):

currently H1 is having -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;

change -webkit-margin-before and -webkit-margin-after.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how works AngularJS (I've never used) but have you tried to set

```
margin: 0;
```

or

```
padding:0;
```

or both?

Maybe is only a css problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reset your default values like this

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Its kinda some attribute have some default value of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this:

```
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
```